# U.S. Equivalent of French T80 for Sourdough Pain de Campagne

Tags: flour, sourdough, french-cuisine

I'm a home sourdough baker in the U.S. and want to try a recipe that calls for the French T80 flour. Some questions:
- I have read T80 described as half whole wheat/half bread flour, and also as all bread flour (i.e., white flour). Can it really be one or the other?
- What is the equivalent of T80 in the U.S., if any?
- If there is no equivalent, what comes close, or what combination of flours would come close?

Comment: Just add a little whole wheat to bread flour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to look for a high gluten bread flour, in the 14% protein area.  [I found this helpful for understanding different flours.](https://www.weekendbakery.com/posts/understanding-flour-types/)  In the [Fresh Loaf Discussion Forum](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/37548/miche-100-organic-t80-wheat-flour), a user suggests combining whole wheat and bread flour in a ratio of 80/20.

Here in the US, you probably have access to King Arthur flours.  Their whole wheat is 14%, white whole wheat is 13%, and bread flour is 12.7% protein.  I doubt you want to go 100% whole wheat flour, so you could use some of the information I provided to create a blend that would work well.

[It looks like you could also order from French T80 here.](https://www.lepicerie.com/pastry-ingredients/ingredients/french-flours-traditional-and-organic/le-moulin-dauguste-organic-wheat-flour-t80/) Although, I should point out that this product description is a little confusing because it describes T45 flour below, and a protein content of 10%, but you might be able to contact them for the product you desire.